# Spark Multiple Joins

Tags: apache-spark

Using spark context, I would like to perform multiple joins between
rdd's, where the number of rdd's to be joined should be dynamic.
I would like the result to be unfolded, for example:

```
val rdd1  = sc.parallelize(List((1,1.0),(11,11.0), (111,111.0)))
val rdd2  = sc.parallelize(List((1,2.0),(11,12.0), (111,112.0)))
val rdd3  = sc.parallelize(List((1,3.0),(11,13.0), (111,113.0)))
val rdd4  = sc.parallelize(List((1,4.0),(11,14.0), (111,114.0)))
val rdd11 = rdd1.join(rdd2).join(rdd3).join(rdd4)
.foreach(println)
```

generates the following output:

```
(11,(((11.0,12.0),13.0),14.0))

(111,(((111.0,112.0),113.0),114.0))

(1,(((1.0,2.0),3.0),4.0))
```

I would like to:

1. Unfold the values, e.g first line should read:
   (11, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0).
2. Do it dynamically so that it can work on any dynamic number
   of rdd's to be joined.

Any ideas would be appreciated,

Eli.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `join`, I would use `union` followed by `groupByKey` to achieve what you desire.

Here is what I would do -

```
val emptyRdd = sc.emptyRDD[(Int, Double)]
val listRdds = List(rdd1, rdd2, rdd3, rdd4) // satisfy your dynamic number of rdds
val unioned = listRdds.fold(emptyRdd)(_.union(_))
val grouped = unioned.groupByKey
grouped.collect().foreach(println(_))
```

This will yields the result:

```
(1,CompactBuffer(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
(11,CompactBuffer(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0))
(111,CompactBuffer(111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0))
```

**Updated**:

If you would still like to use `join`, this is how to do it with somewhat complicated foldLeft functions -

```
val joined = rddList match {
  case head::tail => tail.foldLeft(head.mapValues(Array(_)))(_.join(_).mapValues {
    case (arr: Array[Double], d: Double) => arr :+ d
  })
  case Nil => sc.emptyRDD[(Int, Array[Double])]
}
```

And  `joined.collect` will yield

```
res14: Array[(Int, Array[Double])] = Array((1,Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)), (11,Array(11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0)), (111,Array(111.0, 112.0, 113.0, 114.0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Those rdd's are actually being read from files and I need them ordered (rdd1, rdd2 etc). Is the order of rdd's preserved or I might get "random" order when running in real hdfs and multi nodes? Eli.

Comment: I am not sure about the order. But you can find out yourself by trying my code above.

Answer (score 0):

Others with this problem may find [groupWith](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.groupWith) helpful. From the docs:

```
>>> w = sc.parallelize([("a", 5), ("b", 6)])
>>> x = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 4)])
>>> y = sc.parallelize([("a", 2)])
>>> z = sc.parallelize([("b", 42)])
>>> [(x, tuple(map(list, y))) for x, y in sorted(list(w.groupWith(x, y, z).collect()))]
[('a', ([5], [1], [2], [])), ('b', ([6], [4], [], [42]))]
```